# error Method name expected

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

  int[] ml = new int[10] ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );

  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ml.Length), "Length");


}
```

I get this error can someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Error   1   Method name expected    C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs   21  24  WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] ml = new int[10] ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );
```

Should be

```
int[] ml = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

Comment: Error 1 Invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']' C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 21 36 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @randy: See my edit; you can't specify an array rank (length) when you provide an explicit list of items. When you do that, the length is determined for you.

Comment: I am watching VTC training videos and they have it the way I said before and it works for them. I tried typing it the exact way they have it in the video and I wasnt able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

In C# array values are surrounded by `{` and `}` and not parens.  Switch to using them in the array declaration and the error will go away.

```
int[] ml = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```